# SQL select to find only where 2 column values correspond to only 1 column id

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This seems simple to me, but for some reason I cannot get my head to pump out the right SQL. I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a primary key constraint violation with an update statement I need to run and the primary key constraint is made up of 6 columns put together to make a unique.

I need to do a select on main_id and ONLY bring back the results where the main_id is the SAME main_id, but main_id can EQUAL 2 different document_id's.

IE: Looking for where the same unique main_id = document_id value 10 and also where the same unique main_id = document_id value 20.

My final purpose is wheverever say main_id = document_id 10, I need to delete the row with the document_id 10, leaving only the row with the document_id 20, as both main_id and document_id are PART OF the primary key constraint. The "10" is trash and shouldn't be there... and as soon as I can clean that up, I can run my update statement to fix this big mess.

I have tried using "IN" in the where clause, but then I get ALL instances of 10 and 20, which I do not want or need....... I just simply need to know where 10 and 20 exist TOGETHER with the shared main_id being the same.

Comment: I think some sample data would go a long way in trying to explain what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
delete from sometable
where main_id in (
  select A.main_id from sometable as A
  inner join sometable as B on A.main_id = B.main_id
  where A.document_id = 10
  and B.document_id = 20
)
and document_id = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a way to return the list of rows which have more than one main_id, that can be done using this:

```
SELECT main_id, document_id
FROM
    table
WHERE
    main_id IN (
    SELECT
       main_id
    FROM
       table
    GROUP BY
       main_id
    HAVING
       count(*) > 1
)
```

Having that, it's easy to convert it to a `DELETE` expression, just replace the first `SELECT main_id, document_id` with a `DELETE`, and you are done.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, you gave me good ideas on how to come up with a select that would show me what I wanted.
I wanted to find the main_id shared (duplicated if you will) by 2 different document_id values.

Here's what I came up with from your code samples:
||||  
select main_id, document_id, create_timestamp, created_by from document_audit where main_id in (select a.main_id from document_audit as a inner join document_audit as b on a.main_id = b.main_id where a.document_id = 10 and b.document_id = 20) and document_id IN (10, 20) ORDER BY main_id  
||||
This gave me the main_id's I needed.

Comment: I couldn't get the code block to work on here. I tried 'code' ... maybe I need to try [code] testing [code]....... anyways the above select gave me the same main_id that was shared by the 2 different value document_id's and this allowed me to find and go delete the record that included the document_id 10 that I wanted to remove.

Comment: Then the correct answer is the one by @will_, I didn't get that you wanted specifically rows with documentID IN (10, 20) (which should be redundant and a syntax error - you are not specifying the origin table - in your code snippet).

Comment: Well, redundant or not, it works(ed). It showed every instance of main_id that corresponded to document_id 10 and every instance of main_id that corresponded to document_id 20 right next to each other due to the ORDER BY and this is exactly what I needed to find out. Thanks WILL!